# Change Event Response

Tags: php, laravel, sockets, events

when I trigger an event, the channel it's being broadcasted on is getting this format of response:

```
{"channel":"events","event":"App\\Events\\RealTimeMessage","data":"{\"message\":\"a\",\"channel\":\"events\"}"}
```

I can change the `data` part from `broadcastWith` and the previous output will look like this:

```
{"channel":"events","event":"App\\Events\\RealTimeMessage","data":"{\"a\"}"}
```

the code is:

```
public function broadcastWith(){
        return [$this->message];
    }
```

But I want the response to be like this:
`"a"`.

Comment: Please show the current code you use to change the `data` part

Comment: how about `return $this->message;` without the `[]` ?

Comment: @apokryfos, it takes only array.